# shell_exec('/usr/sbin/i2cget -y 1 *') don't work

Tags: php, raspberry-pi, shell-exec, i2c

I use a raspberrypi to control an Arduino UNO board.
I try to use i2c with php to reports on a site heberger on raspberry.
Php but do not want to run `shell_exec ("/usr/sbin/i2cget -y 1 0x04 0x02 b")`.
If I put it Inthe shell I see the right result.
And when I try with `shell_exec("ls-the art");` the site displays the correct result!

where is my problem? I gave all rights to the script, but not more matches, the path to i2cget is correct.

what can I try to solve this problem?

Comment: `/ 1 0x04 0x02 usr/sbin/i2cget-y b` isn't a valid shell command

Comment: sorry i have change for the good command i don't know why the code have change on copy/paste

Comment: ah ok, looked weird :)

Answer (score 0):

You could read the fine manual, run the command as root, run the service that runs the command as root, configure the service do include /usr/sbin/ in its PATH, load the necessary kernel modules, assert that the given chip and data addresses make sense and post your question to an [appropriate audience](http://superuser.com).

Comment: I have try to use `shell_exec ("sudo /usr/sbin/i2cget -y 1 0x04 0x02 b`) but this don't work !! and where can i find _an appropriate audience_

Comment: There is no need to restate your analysis of the problem. I have understood your question and given you several clues to what may be the cause.

Comment: i try include /usr/sbin on my php code, but nothing. i run that with sudo it's the same result.
but when i run the same command on shell no problem rasperry readings is good.

Answer (score -2):

Try like below.

Marked `/usr/sbin/i2cget` as UID.
- or -

```
sudo chmod 4755 /usr/sbin/i2cget
```

It works!